# HTML, JavaScript and ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html page with javascript code.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Sink The Battle Ship</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Battleship</h1>
      <script src="battleship.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var location = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var numberOfGuesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;
var guess;
var guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number from 0-6):");
var guessedLocation = parseInt(guess);
console.log(guess);
console.log(guessedLocation);
```

Every time I launch the html in browser, the prompt displays and when I enter a value, it gives me an error "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". It looks like the browser is trying to re-direct to a page with the value I entered. Any idea what is going wrong here? I tried opening the html in different browsers and still no luck.

Comment: That did not help.

Comment: Please check my answer, I just commented here to say that, in my 5 years of js development, this is the first time I saw this error, hahaha, I had no idea this could happen but it does make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are redefining a global variable, called location.

When you declare a variable like this

```
var location = 1;
```

is the same as doing this

```
window.location = 1;
```

Location is a browser variable used to define in which page (location) the user is in.

You can do two things,

1 - Rename your variable location to: $location, location_2, my_location

```
var myLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

2 - Create a local scope

```
(function(){
    var location = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    var numberOfGuesses = 0;
    var isSunk = false;
    var guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number from 0-6):");
    var guessedLocation = parseInt(guess);
    console.log(guess);
    console.log(guessedLocation);
})()
```

Also, stop re-declaring the variable guess, only use ONE 'var' for every variable name

```js
(function(){
  var location = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  var numberOfGuesses = 0;
  var isSunk = false;
  var guess;
  var guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number from 0-6):");
  var guessedLocation = parseInt(guess);
  console.log(location);
  console.log(guessedLocation);
  guessedLocation == location ? console.log('you sank me!') : console.log('ha! missed...')
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Sink The Battle Ship</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Battleship</h1>
      <script src="battleship.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved my problem. I am just starting JavaScript and getting my head around it.

Comment: No problems, just remember to mark the best answer as your answer so we can get those sweet reputation points